# Composer - failed opening required for phpseclib

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, virtual-machine, phpseclib

I am trying to run a PHP file in a Vagrant VM which also uses composer for the build.

I am getting the following errors:

```
PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/CLIENT/vendor/composer/../phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/ispe/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66

Warning: require(/var/www/CLIENT/vendor/composer/../phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/CLIENT/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/CLIENT/vendor/composer/../phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/bootstrap.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/CLIENT/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/CLIENT/vendor/composer/../phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/bootstrap.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/CLIENT/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
```

Now as far as I can tell, phpseclib shouldn't be required for this particular functionality, or anything else (though I haven't 100% confirmed the anything else bit yet).

Even so, I decided to add it to my composer.json ("phpseclib/phpseclib": "2.0.4") to get rid of the errors, with no luck.

I'm fairly new to Composer, so I am wondering precisely what I might be doing wrong here or what needs to be setup.

I can confirm that the directory `/var/www/CLIENT/vendor/composer/../phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/` exists, however there is no file bootstrap.php inside the directory.

Instead I see the following:

```
Crypt  File  Math  Net  System
```

EDIT: I also want to clarify that the file autoload.php is inside the vendor directory and that the PHP version of the VM is 7.0.

Comment: Composer does not only download your dependencies, it also recursively downloads dependencies of dependencies. If you are not using this library directly, it is likely a dependency of one that you are using, or one that one of those is using. You can try grepping for phpseclib in */composer.json within your vendor directory to get a better idea what is including it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I strongly believe that the `cache` is the problem, It cannot be 100% sure but try destroying your Vagrant instance, or

You could follow the following steps:

1. Delete the `vendor` folder
2. Delete `composer.lock`
3. Run the command `composer clearcache` (or `clear-cache`)
4. Run `composer install`

Answer (score 2):

Oneliner for easy copy/pasting:

```
rm -rf vendor composer.lock && composer clearcache && composer install
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Especially as removing the lock file can have severe consequences

Comment: This should probably be a comment under the accepted answer as it does what the answer suggests in a single line

Comment: I'm getting the same error but I don't have any composer.lock or composer.json files so I can't do the reinstall. I have no idea how this is even working without those files.